# Is there an equivalent of a FOR UPDATE lock for views in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, view, locking

I have an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger on a `view`:

```sql
CREATE VIEW usr_view AS
  SELECT
    us.id,
    uv.col1,
    uv.col2,
    uv.col3
  FROM usr_static AS us
  LEFT JOIN usr_version AS uv ON us.id = us.id AND uv.create_time = (
    SELECT MAX(uv2.create_time)
    FROM usr_version AS uv2
    WHERE uv2.id = us.id
  )
```

This trigger inserts a new row into one of the underlying tables of the view:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION shared.on_update_view() RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
    view_name text := TG_TABLE_NAME;
    schema_name text := TG_TABLE_SCHEMA;
    version_table_name text := schema_name || '.' || view_name || '_version';
BEGIN
    -- Insert into the version table
    EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %s (col1, col2, col3) SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM (SELECT $1.*) AS new_table', version_table_name)
    USING NEW;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;
```

The problem I'm facing is that when two `UPDATE` queries run on the view at the same time, there are race conditions:

```sql
// row 1 in usr_version
(id, col1, col2, col3, ...)  VALUES (1, 'A', 'B', 'C', ...)
```

```sql
-- query 1
UPDATE usr_view SET col1 = 'foo' WHERE id = 1;

-- query 2
UPDATE usr_view SET col2 = 'bar' WHERE id = 1;
```

`query 1` will insert the following row in `usr_version`:

```
(id, col1, col2, col3, ...)  VALUES (1, 'foo', 'B', 'C', ...)
```

But because `query 2` runs at the same time, it will insert:

```
(id, col1, col2, col3, ...)  VALUES (1, 'A', 'Bar', 'C', ...)
```

And because the `view` shows the latest created row in `usr_version`, the view will look like:

```sql
-- if query 1 inserted faster:
(id, col1, col2, col3, ...)  VALUES (1, 'foo', 'B', 'C', ...)

-- if query 2 inserted faster:
(id, col1, col2, col3, ...)  VALUES (1, 'A', 'Bar', 'C', ...)
```

However, the expected result would be:

```sql
(id, col1, col2, col3, ...)  VALUES (1, 'Foo', 'Bar', 'C', ...)
```

To my understanding, Postgres sets a `FOR UPDATE` lock when updating a row of a `table`, to prevent such situations from happening. It seems though, as if Postgres does not do something similar for updating a `view` using a `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger...

What would be the best way to ensure that the two queries execute serially, such that the expected result is achieved?

Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Without the table definitions, it is hard to figure out what this does. You seem to be referencing 3 different tables, but there only roles for 2, so did you just give one of them two different names? How does the the id column from usr_version (or usr_view_version) get populated?

Answer (score 0):

Your view definition will only work if there is no more than a single (logical) row. Is that your use case? The view would perform better if you rewrote it to

```
CREATE VIEW usr AS
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3
FROM usr_version
ORDER BY create_time DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

and create an index on `usr_view.create_time`.

But I don't think that there is a commendable way to have updates on your view be safe from race conditions. You would have to place a heavy lock on the table itself, which is a bad idea, because it prevents autovacuum from doing its job.

Go with a different model:

```
/* use a regular table, not a view */
CREATE TABLE usr (
   col1 text,
   col2 text,
   col3 text
);

/* make sure there can be only a single row */
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON usr ((1));

CREATE TABLE usr_version (
   col1 text,
   col2 text,
   col3 text,
   create_time timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);

CREATE FUNCTION upd_usr() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   INSERT INTO usr_version (col1, col2, col3, create_time)
   VALUES (NEW.col1, NEW.col2, NEW.col3, clock_timestamp());

   RETURN NEW;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER upd_usr AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON usr FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION upd_usr();
```

This is automatically free from race conditions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! No it is not my use case, it is a simplified version of the actual view, which joins two tabels: 1 with static values & 1 with versioned values. The simplified view just demonstrates how only the newest versioned row is used, which opens up the race condition. So given that there can actually be multiple rows, I guess your solution will not work...

Comment: That is not the important point of my answer. The key point is that you should use a regular table instead of the view, and persist the versions with a trigger in another table.

Comment: I see what you're saying. This is the common `history` table pattern I believe. But we have decided on tracking changes in a slightly different way. Here we have one `static` and one `version` table and we join these together in a view. Effectively this means that we must use the `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger...

Comment: I don't believe that you can avoid race condition with your original design.